# KGDB serial port reinitialised after boot

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port, yocto, beagleboneblack, kgdb

I have been fighting with this issue for a while and slowly giving up on it. I am working with Yocto on my Beaglebone Black board. I want to be able to use KGDB to debug kernel modules and kernel itself. I have modified device tree to enable UART1 exclusively for KGDB and modified kernel settings to enable KGDB.

During early boot a bootloader configures serial port to 115200n8 settings and stops execution waiting for GDB from my host machine to connect to the BeagleBone via serial port and allow it for single stepping of the code. The problem appears later on when I allow the code to continue with execution. Host machine on which I run GDB stops responding and seems to have no connection to the Beaglebone anymore. Once I log in into Beaglebone using terminal I find that serial port settings for KGDB got changed to some defaults with 9600 baudrate. What might be causing that change? What part of the linux initilisation might be affecting my serial port settings? I am still very new to Linux and its concepts, so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you enabled console polling mode? KGdb doesn't work with consoles that uses interrupts.

Comment: @0andriy I am not sure in which mode the serial port is being configured for KGDB. The KGDB does work up until 
`kernel_init() -> try_to_run_init_process("/sbin/init")`
Afterwards serial port does seem to get reconfigured.

I do not know how to debug the sysvinit. I was briefly looking through its scripts but can't see anything obvious over there that touches /dev/ttyO1 that kgdb is configured to use.